# Setting a random window title in C++

Tags: visual-c++

i wanna set my window title to a random string but i cant figure out how.
I tried to use a random string generator but i dont get how to implement it into the window title.
The random string generator i tried.

```
void gen_random(char *s, const int len) {
static const char alphanum[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    s[i] = alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];
}

s[len] = 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `_T` macro to make sure that the string is in the correct format and set your title using the `SetConsoleTitle` function :

```
SetConsoleTitle(_T(*YOUR_RANDOM_TITLE_VAR*));
```

Comment: And how do i implement this with the random function?

Comment: You can do it just like this `SetConsoleTitle(_T(s));` after the for loop or after calling the `gen_random` function.

Comment: This should be `SetConsoleTitleA(s)` because OP uses a `char` string. The `_T()` macro is not necessary.